# How to count current showing products in Shopify 2.0 dawn theme?

Tags: html, filter, pagination, shopify, liquid

In collection page of dawn(version 5.0.0) theme Shopify, there is and inbuilt functionality to see the total number of products. 
[image] 
I want show that how many current product are showing when more products are getting into pagination.
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 modification in 2 files of dawn theme.

1. in `facets.liquid` file add below code under the span id `ProductCountDesktop`.

{% if next_link %}
{{ offset | plus: 1 }} - {{ offset | plus: page_size }} of 
{% else %} 
{% capture itemsOnCurrentPage %} 
{{ results.all_products_count | minus: offset }} 
{% endcapture %} 
{% if results.all_products_count > 0 %}{{ offset | plus: 1 }}{% else %}{{ offset }} {% endif %}- {{ offset | plus: itemsOnCurrentPage }} of  
{% endif %}

2. now replace `render: facets` with below code in `main-collection-product-grid.liquid` file.

{%- paginate collection.products by section.settings.products_per_page -%} 
{% render 'facets', results: collection, enable_filtering: section.settings.enable_filtering,
filter_type: section.settings.filter_type, enable_sorting: section.settings.enable_sorting, collapse_on_larger_devices: section.settings.collapse_on_larger_devices,
offset : paginate.current_offset,next_link:paginate.next.is_link,page_size:paginate.page_size  %} 
{%- endpaginate -%}